# How do I use the cascade option in Symfony2 Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, cascade

I'm trying to understand the [`cascade`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) option in **Doctrine** in **Symfony2**.

I would like to be able to delete a child entity (and not trigger the foreign key constraint error.)

I have 3 entities:

**Report**

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Response", mappedBy="report")
*/
protected $responses;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Response", mappedBy="report")
*/
protected $sms;
```

**Response**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Report", inversedBy="responses")
 */
protected $report;
```

**SMS**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Report")
 */
protected $report;
```

Now I would like to delete a `Response` entity but I get

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`mybundle`.`sms`, CONSTRAINT `FK_B0A93A77BB333E0D` FOREIGN KEY (`reportId`) REFERENCES `report` (`id`))

Where do I use the `cascade` option and which option should I use (`detach` or `remove`)?

I can do a lot of trial and error to figure this out, but I was hoping for an expert explanation, so I don't overlook something.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Report", inversedBy="responses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reportId", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $report;
```

And then update yor schema. It will add database level Cascading

Comment: Yo.. That worked!  Thanks.  I think I'm going to need to revisit this question shortly, though.  I will also want to delete reports.. I'll get to that in a minute..

Comment: Easy answer Ziumin, thumbs up, but I imagine this deletes all children from the parent? Is there an option to keep those children? For example: I want to delete a user(parent), but keep his blogposts(children). Then make the author of the blogpost null or unknown or something...

Comment: Try `onDelete="SET NULL"`.

Answer (score 12):

Ziumin's answer

> using the `onDelete` option for the `ORM JoinColumn`

method worked when you want to delete a child item ([Owning Side](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)).

But if you want to delete a `Response` which is a parent item ([Inverse Side](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)), this is when `cascade` comes in handy.  In the `Report` entity I added the following for each of its collections (OneToMany relationships):

**Report**

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Response", mappedBy="report", cascade={"remove"})
*/
protected $responses;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SMS", mappedBy="report", cascade={"remove"})
*/
protected $sms;
```

Now, when I delete a `Report`, it removes all of its associated entries in the `Response` and `SMS` tables.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `cascade=all` for update all actions.

**Report**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Response", mappedBy="report", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $responses;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SMS", mappedBy="report", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $sms;
```

Comment: " Do not blindly apply cascade=all to all associations as it will unnecessarily degrade the performance of your application. For each cascade operation that gets activated Doctrine also applies that operation to the association, be it single or collection valued." -> http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations